# Unable to disable click event of a span

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to disable a span. My attempt is as below.

```
<span @click="confirm" disabled="true">click here</span>
```

But it will not disabled. Where I was wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: `disable` is not a valid HTML attribute for a `<span>` element. If the element is meant to be clickable anyway, why are you not using `<button>`?

Comment: So is there any way to disable a span?

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` if you want to not let it be accessible, or you can simply have a guard clause in the `confirm()` method that doesn't execute the code further if the button should be disabled

Answer (score 1):

You can use css class to disable the span. If you want to make it dynamic simply use **Class Binding** eg `:class="your_variable"`

*For Class and Style Bindings you can use this reference*

vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax
[Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

```js
const app = new Vue({
  methods: {
    confirm(){
    alert('hello');
    }
  }
})
app.$mount("#app")
```

```css
.disable-click{
pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<h2>Enable click</h2>
<span v-on:click="confirm()">Click</span>

<h2>Disable click</h2>
<span v-on:click="confirm()" class="disable-click">Disable Click</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Al tough this does seem like a nice vue answer to me (I don't know vue) you should always add some explanation to your code so the OP understands what you have done.

Comment: I added some explanation